# Using jupyter notebook to practice some data analysis and my return statement changes my dictionary order

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

My code:

```
def chickenpox_by_sex():

    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv("NISPUF17.csv")

    male_1dose_nopox = df[(df['P_NUMVRC'] >=1) & (df['HAD_CPOX'] == 1) & 
                       (df['SEX'] == 1)]
    female_1dose_nopox = df[(df['P_NUMVRC'] >=1) & (df['HAD_CPOX'] == 1) & (df['SEX'] == 2)]
    male_1dose_pox = df[(df['P_NUMVRC'] >=1) & (df['HAD_CPOX'] == 2) & (df['SEX'] == 1)]
    female_1dose_pox = df[(df['P_NUMVRC'] >=1) & (df['HAD_CPOX'] == 2) & (df['SEX'] == 2)]

    ratio_male = male_1dose_nopox.shape[0]/male_1dose_pox.shape[0]
    ratio_female = female_1dose_nopox.shape[0]/female_1dose_pox.shape[0]

    ratio = [ratio_male, ratio_female]
    sex = ['male', 'female']

    di = {}

    di['male'] = ratio[0]
    di['female'] = ratio[1]

    print(di)
    return di
```

When I call the function:

my print statement outputs the following:

```
{'male': 0.009675583380762664, 'female': 0.0077918259335489565}
```

my return statement returns the following:

```
{'female': 0.0077918259335489565, 'male': 0.009675583380762664}
```

I have no idea why it does this and I wouldnt care that much but I need the return statement to put the male first in this case.
I have searched everywhere but cant find an answer for this.
Please help me out!

Comment: `return` statements are for functions. Where is the function?

Comment: Is up(before the imports). he didn't include it in the code.

Comment: Ha, I missed that, thanks :)

Comment: Why exactly does it need to be returned in that order? It would be helpful to see the function it returns it to.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are unordered in python. You could use a SortedDict from the 3rd party lib sortedcontainers. Or you could use a list of tuples instead of a dict.

Comment: The werid thing is, in vscode this runs just as I expect it to. In jupyter notebook it swaps the order...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you run your jupyter notebook at different times and see different results. If there's no guarantee that elements will stay ordered then it seems like anything is possible.